# pass the code of java to work for java/android

Tags: java, android

I have 3 .java files: main.java, separetdat.java and token.java

### main.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tokenizer ob1=new Tokenizer();
    LinkedList listaDeCoord=new LinkedList();
    SepararDatos oSepararDatos=new SepararDatos();
    ob1.leerPath();
    ob1.getDataFromFile();

    listaDeCoord=ob1.listaTokens;
    listaDeCoord=oSepararDatos.getLinkedList(listaDeCoord);
    double[] vectorDeDatos; //= new double[listaDeCoord.size()];
    double[] vectorIndex;


    vectorDeDatos=oSepararDatos.getArrayData(listaDeCoord);


    vectorIndex=oSepararDatos.getArrayIndex(vectorDeDatos);      

}
}
```

### separetdat.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SepararDatos {

public void SepararDatos()
{

}

public double[] getArrayIndex(double[] vector)
{
    double[] vectorIndex=new double[vector.length/3];
    int index=0,i=0;

    while (index<vector.length)
    {
        vectorIndex[i]=vector[index];
        index=index+3;
        i++;
    }

    return vectorIndex;
}

     public LinkedList getLinkedList(LinkedList lista)
{
    String linea="";
    StringTokenizer st;
    String palabra="";
    LinkedList palabras=new LinkedList();
    //lista=new LinkedList();
    int j=0;
    char c;
    int indice=0;

    for (int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
    {
        linea=lista.get(i).toString();
        st=new StringTokenizer(linea);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            palabras.add((st.nextToken()));
        }
    }

return palabras;
}



public double[] getArrayData(LinkedList lista)
{
    double[] vectorPalabras=new double[lista.size()];


    for (int i=0;i<vectorPalabras.length;i++)
    {

        vectorPalabras[i]=Double.parseDouble(lista.get(i).toString());

    }

return vectorPalabras;
}
}
```

### token.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tokenizer {

String strFile;
BufferedReader br;
String strLine;
StringTokenizer st = null;
int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;
LinkedList lista=new LinkedList();
LinkedList listaTokens=new LinkedList();


public void Tokenizer()
{

}

public void leerPath ()
{
    strFile = "path of the txt file.txt";
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
{
        System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);
}

}

public double[] getDataFromFile()
{
    double[] vector=new double[lista.size()];

    try
    {
        while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lineNumber++;
    //break comma separated line using ","
    //st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");
    st = new StringTokenizer(strLine);
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
                //display csv values

                System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber + ", Token # " + tokenNumber + ", Token : "+ st.nextToken());

                tokenNumber++;
    }
                //reset token number
                tokenNumber = 0;
                lista.add(strLine);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
{
        System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);
}
    listaTokens=lista;


    for (int i=0;i<vector.length;i++)
    {

        vector[i]=Double.parseDouble(lista.get(i).toString());

    }

    return vector;
}
}
```

When I create the java project, it works perfectly, but when I create an Android project, it does not work. What do I need to change the original java code so that it works in Android?

---

im sorry for my question to be how to put it mmmm dumb
basically what i like to now is how to call the methods from the other 2 clases in Activity,
activity has to call form the other 2 classes, simple example will be let say
activity.java has  to call from calculate.java the method that prints out the result

activity.java
calls result from sum
calls result from multiply
prints the results

name.java
let say it does a sum in one function
return sum result.

2 function does  multiply 2 numbers
returm multiply results.

Comment: There's waaay too much code there, and you're not giving any information about _how_ or _what_ fails when you try to put it in an Android project. Don't count on people doing it for you here.

Comment: im sorry for my question to be how to put it mmmm dumb
basically what i like to now is how to call the methods from the other 2 clases in Activity,
activity has to call form the other 2 classes, simple example will be let say
activity.java has  to call from calculate.java the method that prints out the result

activity.java
calls result from sum
calls result from multiply
prints the results


name.java
let say it does a sum in one funtion
return sum result.

2 function does  multiply 2 numbers
returm multiply results.

Comment: all that belongs in your question. Please edit it (there's a link just for that below the tags)

Answer (score 1):

I've never liked answered on here that are simply "Read the documentation" followed by links, but I think that's the best answer in this case.

I strongly recomment reading [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) on application fundamentals to get an idea of how the android framework works, as well as following the tutorials on the android dev site. I'm sure there is nothing wrong with you code, but the android framework doesn't work like java does.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is plain old Java SE code that has "System.out.println()" statements to print to the console. How were you expecting to run this on Android?

Android apps *are* written in Java, but they have to be built as an Android application.  You can't just take random Java code and expect it to magically run on an Android device.

StackOverflow is also for providing information to help you program... it's not for people to "give you the code", and it doesn't seem like you've done enough research to even know how to use advice people could give you...

There are tons of resources to start learning Android, just search for them on the web.  But at least to start you off, here's the [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Comment: im sorry for my question to be how to put it mmmm dumb
basically what i like to now is how to call the methods from the other 2 clases in Activity,
activity has to call form the other 2 classes

Comment: mi new code whe pass to java/android no longer has "system.out.print" and many thigs that are usless whit android

Answer (score 0):

The structure of an Android project is entirely different from a regular Java project. Android has no `main`, instead it has a main `Activity`. There are also many other differences; basically too many to cover in a single answer.

You should check out Google's [Android Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). Then check out the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html). This will give you an idea as to how you can convert your project over to Android. The Notepad tutorial especially, will give you an idea as to how an Android project is structured, and how the various components communicate with each other.